# Undefined Behavior in Unions with Standard Layout structs

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior, constexpr, unions

Take the following code

```
union vec
{
    struct
    {
        float x, y, z;
    };

    float data[3];

    constexpr vec() : data{} {}
};

constexpr vec make_vec(float x, float y, float z)
{
    vec res;
    res.data[0] = x;
    res.data[1] = y;
    res.z = z;
    return res;
}

int main()
{
    constexpr vec out = make_vec(0, 1, 2);
    std::cout << out.z << '\n';
}
```

I make use of constexpr here to determine whether the code is undefined behavior or not, as the undefined behavior will cause a compilation error.

§9.2/19:

> If a standard-layout union contains two or more standard-layout structs that share a common initial sequence, and if the standard-layout union object currently contains one of these standard-layout structs, it is permitted to inspect the common initial part of any of them.

From this, I would assume that everything in the code would be defined behavior.

Compiling with `g++ main.cpp -o out -std=c++17`, I get the message `error: change of the active member of a union from 'vec::data' to 'vec::<anonymous>'`.

I thought that to comply with the standard, I might've had to change it to this--

```
union vec
{
    struct
    {
        float x, y, z;
    };

    struct
    {
        float data[3];
    };

    constexpr vec() : data{} {}
};
```

But I get the same error.

Is this truly undefined behavior? Is there perhaps another part of the standard that I've missed, or am I simply misinterpreting the standard?

Comment: `float x, y, z;` and `float data[3];` do not have a common initial sequence (well, maybe `x` and `data[0]` count, I'm not sure), so in a `union` it is UB to write to `data[1]` or `data[2]`, and then read from `y` or `z`, or vice versa.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Ok. I think I misunderstood what a "common initial sequence" was

Comment: A "common initial sequence" means if two or more class types have the same starting field types, and those fields have the same alignments, etc.  So, for example: `struct s1 { float x, y, z; };` and `struct s2 { float f1, f2; int i3; };` the common initial sequence is the 1st two `float`s.

Comment: Ok. I assumed that 3 floats would be the same as a float array of size 3, but I can see why that is not true.

Comment: The alignments between the individual `float`s could be different than the alignments between the array elements, for instance.

Comment: Since we are talking about UB per the standard: Anonymous `struct`s like this are not allowed in ISO C++ (but are in C). The compiler allows them as an extension.

Comment: Could you quote the standard? I haven't heard of that

Comment: @Jcsq6 You have https://eel.is/c++draft/class.union.anon which defines how anonymous unions as class members behave, but there is no equivalent for non-union unnamed classes as members in the standard, so it would just be a member declaration that doesn't declare anything, which is not allowed.

Comment: @Jcsq6 Also add the `-pedantic` or `-pedantic-errors` flags to the compiler command line and it will tell you that this is an extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is UB.

After you write to `float data[3];` part of the union, you are not allowed to read the `struct { float x, y, z; };`

This is as simple as that.

> that share a common initial sequence

Doesn't cover these two, as an array is not the same as a float followed by another float.

**Important edit**

The answer above assumed the code was UB as the `.x` and `.y` members would not be valid. As @user17732522 points out. It is a bit more subtle than that.

`.x` and `.y` are returned uninitialized and would have undefined values. But the write to the `.z` member indeed sets the active member of the union. As such, as long as the calling code only reads the `.z` member, everything is defined and correct.

Comment: Is there any way to achieve this, while being defined behavior?

Comment: Not in standard C++, no.  But non-standard compiler extensions may allow for this kind of code.

Comment: The line `res.z = z;` will end the lifetime of the `data` member and make the anonymous struct the active member (ignoring for a moment that anonymous structs are not ISO C++). I don't think there is any undefined behavior here. The constant expression evaluation only fails because changing the active member in a constant expression is explicitly forbidden in C++17 (but not C++20).

Comment: oh. @user17732522 . right. I had assumed the code read all three. Yikes. Let me edit, and much thanks for pointing this out.